# Como faço para deixar meus botões sem sobrepor o menu?

Tags: html, css3

Adicionei 2 botões em meu site, e quando faço a rolagem para baixo ele fica em cima do menu, gostaria de saber como faço para deixar eles parados e quando eu rolar pra baixo ele não ficar em cima do menu. Segue o código:

## Portfólio

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#profile">Sobre mim</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fale conosco</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</aside>

<div class="menu-spacing"></div>

<section id="home" class="home main-bg section">
    <div class="main-content home-content">
        <div class="home-text-content">
            <h6>Olá, eu sou</h6>
            <h2>Gustavo Gomes</h2>
            <h6>Desenvolvedor Front-end</h6>

 <div class="banner-buttons">
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/gusta-gomes/" target="_blank" title="Ver perfil no Linkedin"
                    class="button-padrao button-padrao-orange" alt="Ver perfil no Linkedin">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in">
                    </i>
                  
                    LinkedIn
                </a>

                <a href="https://github.com/GustaKsh" target="_blank" title="Ver perfil no GitHub"
                    class="button-padrao button-padrao-orange" alt="Ver perfil no GitHub">
                    <i class="fa-brands fa-github-in">
                    </i>
                    
                    GitHub
                </a>
            </div>
```

Segue o código CSS

```
.menu {
position: fixed;
background: var(--white-color);
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 0.1rem solid var(--light-gray-color);
```

}

.menu-content {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
padding-top: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;

}

.menu ul {
list-style: none;
display: flex;
}

.menu h1 {
font-size: 2.3rem;
color: var(--primary-color);
}

.menu h1 a {
color: inherit;
}

.menu ul li a {
display: block;
padding: 2rem;
font-size: 1.8rem;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;
color: var(--primary-color);
position: relative;
}

.menu ul li a::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
bottom: 1rem;
left: 25%;
height: 0.2rem;
width: 0;
background: var(--primary-color);
transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.menu ul li a:hover::after {
width: 50%;

}

CSS buttons:

```
.banner-buttons {
display: flex;
margin-top: 3em;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
```

}

.button-padrao-orange {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-left: 1em;
margin-top: 20px;
position: absolute;

}

.button-padrao {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 214px;
height: 50px;
z-index: 10;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0 / 20%);
color: var(--primary-color);
background-color: var(--white-color);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--primary-color), 0 0 15px var(--white-color), 0 0 30px var(--primary-color);
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.3s;
border: 0px solid transparent;
border-radius: 50px;
transition: .2s;
}

.button-padrao:hover {
background: var(--primary-color);
box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--primary-color), 0 0 15px var(--white-color), 0 0 30px var(--primary-color);
color: var(--white-color);
transition-delay: .1s;
}

Answer (score -2):

Se os botões estão sobrepondo o menu quando estão na mesma posição na interface, o z-index deve resolver o seu problema.

O valor padrão do z-index é **auto**, então se você usá-lo somente no menu, defini-lo como "1" vai ser o suficiente pra que sobreponha qualquer outra coisa.

Porém, no seu caso, os botões estão com z-index definido. Então você precisa remover essa propriedade deles ou setar um z-index mais alto para o menu.

Caso você deixe somente o menu com z-index definido, o seguinte já seria suficiente:

```
.menu {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
background: var(--white-color);
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 0.1rem solid var(--light-gray-color);
}
```

Pra entender melhor como essa propriedade do CSS funciona, recomendo dar uma lida nessa documentação:

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)